# How to make element fill remaining width, when sibling has variable width?

Tags: css, layout, forms

In the example below:
[image]

I want the textbox to fill all available space. The problem is the dropdown width cannot be fixed, since its elements are not static. I would like to solve this with just css (no javascript if possible).

I have tried the solutions proposed to similar questions without any luck :(

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ruben_diaz/cAHb8/

Here is the html:

```
<div id="form_wrapper">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/some_action" method="post">
        <span class="category_dropdown_container">
            <select class="chosen chzn-done" name="question[category_id]" id="selQJK">
                <option value="1">General</option>
                <option value="2">Fruits</option>
                <option value="3">Ice Creams</option>
                <option value="4">Candy</option>
            </select>
        </span>
        <span class="resizable_text_box">
            <input id="question_text_box" name="question[what]" placeholder="Write a query..." type="text" />
        </span>
        <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Ask!" />
    </form>
</div>
```

And here the css:

```
#form_wrapper {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 5px;
}
form {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.category_dropdown_container {
}
.resizable_text_box {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
input[type="text"] {
}
input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 80px;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/ugve7/2/)   (tested fine in IE7/8/9/10, Firefox, Chrome, Safari)

- Float the left and right elements.
- In the HTML source code, put both of the floated elements first (this is the most important part).
- Give the middle element `overflow: hidden;` and an implict width of `100%`.
- Give the text box in the middle element a width of `100%`.

```css
.category_dropdown_container {
    float: left;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    float: right;
    ...
}

.resizable_text_box {
    padding: 0 15px 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.resizable_text_box input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="category_dropdown_container">
    <select class="chosen chzn-done" name="question[category_id]" id="selQJK">
        ...
    </select>
</div>

<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Ask!" />

<div class="resizable_text_box">
    <input id="question_text_box" name="question[what]"
           placeholder="Write a query..." type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: If we're allowed to edit the html (which your answer does) then this is the way to do it.

Comment: It was a game changer for me. I came to know that *THE SEQUENCE MATTERS*.Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've just come across this answer while looking for a solution myself and I disagree with the solution here, HTML should be semantic and make logical sense, which this does not. Fudging the HTML order to correct the aesthetics is not the right way to go about fixing the problem.

Answer (score 9):

The relatively recent 'flex' display css property solves this problem for you:

All you need to do is change form's `display` to `inline-flex`, give `.resizable_text_box` `flex-grow: 100;` and give `#question_text_box` `width: 100%`

Full example from the OP:

```
<style>
#form_wrapper {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 5px;
}
form {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
}
.category_dropdown_container {
}
.resizable_text_box {
    border: 1px solid red;
    flex-grow: 100;
}
#question_text_box {
    width: 100%   
}
input[type="text"] {
}
input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 80px;
    float: right;
}
</style>

<div id="form_wrapper">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/some_action" method="post">
        <span class="category_dropdown_container">
            <select class="chosen chzn-done" name="question[category_id]" id="selQJK">
                <option value="1">Options</option>
            </select>
        </span>
        <span class="resizable_text_box">
            <input id="question_text_box" name="question[what]" placeholder="Write a query..." type="text" />
        </span>
        <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Ask!" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Flex-box lets you do what you wanted to do with css for 15 years - its finally here! More info: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2):

Change some of those `<span>` elements to `<div>` elements; then `float:left` the division around your dropdown; then give the one of the right an `overflow:hidden` and the input element inside it a `width:100%;`.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/zkCeG/). [Here it is again with a bigger drop down](http://jsfiddle.net/zkCeG/1).

---

Except that screws up the submit button. So give the `#form_wrapper` non-static positioning (`position:relative`) and position the submit button absolutely. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7gFJ/) and [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/e7gFJ/1).

Comment: Thanks for your time @Richard, but I found the solution provided by Matt more suitable.