# Make an inline element to fill 100% of the remaining space let from another inline element

Tags: html, css

I have a **form** with 3 elements

```
<form>
    <input type="search" value="long text" />
    <select>
        <option>Google</option>
        <option>Bing</option>
    </select>
    <button>Search</button>
</form>
```

I would like to have the **select** and the **button** to have their own width, and the **input** to fill all the remaining space.

I found different solutions but they seems to not work properly.

Following [how-to-make-element-fill-remaining-width-when-sibling-has-variable-width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241186/how-to-make-element-fill-remaining-width-when-sibling-has-variable-width) I get the desired effect (having to add markup and to change the order of the elements) but the **input** is overridden from the other elements, loosing its nice rounded borders.

```
button, select {
    float: right;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
}

.input_wrapper {
    overflow: hidden
}
```

How can I do instead?

- I need a **cross-browser** solution (>=IE7)
- I would avoid (if possible) to use additional markup
- I want to avoid that the the **input** could be overflown and hidden (as explained above).

PS - I usually try to avoid *floats* and stay with *display-block*. But all the suggestions are welcome

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/0k3seaxy/?

Comment: IE7 ?? Really? Windows officially withdrawn support for `XP`... I thought at least everything upto `7` is no more... looks like the day i'm dreaming of isn't coming at all in the near future...  -_-

Comment: Ok, I guess that we can start from IE8. But if there's something that works also on IE7 is obviously better.

Comment: @j08691 yes, exactly like that. But I'm doing some test and found that it behaves like that with the default **box-sizing**. Changing that to *border-box* solved the problem. But I don't get why...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think this can be done by setting the form to "display: table" and then the input, select and button to display: table-cell.

Then set widths on the first 2 elements and make the third element width: 100% and display: block.

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Could be a feasible solution, but I don't want to set the *width* for the other two elements, cause their content is dynamic.