# Make 3 column divs responsive. Help me spot what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

The div elements inside the row are floated left, as described here:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp
and percentage sized.
I tried to apply what was suggested in this link below, in a similar question, but without success:
[Responsive CSS / Inline divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229169/responsive-css-inline-divs)

The divs keep an inline relation of 50% - 100% - 50% and their contents overlap.
Can anyone help me spot what I missed?
Thank you.

In my CSS and HTML I have:

```css
footer[role="contentinfo"] div {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.engage-row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.col-1 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
.col-2 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
}
.col-3 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
.footer-wfix {
  clear: both;
}

/* for illustrative purposes */

.engage-row {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.engage-row > div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<footer id="colophon" role="contentinfo">
<div class="footer-wrap">
  <div class="engage-row">
    <div class="col-1">
      Column 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      Column 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      Column 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-wfix">
      Footer Menu and Site-generator
  </div>
</div>
</footer><!-- #colophon -->
```

Edited the code and am adding the below for clarity:
 - I edited the footer by adding the "engage-row" and it's containing column divs.
 - All divs have inherited box-sizing: border-box.
 - Column 1, Column 2 and Column 3 don't readjust positioning when I decrease the screen size (width); instead of becoming on top of each others, they are changing their size (keeping percentages but becoming smaller), making the containing text and images overlap (text from column 2 goes in front of the image in column 1). I hope I am using the correct terms for clarity.
 - How can I make them readjust the positioning as the screen size changes?
 - PrintScreen: [3column divs in footer](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwA1IuXMUSGIcjJ2TjdzX2pwTEE/view?usp=sharing)

(This is an awesome site. Thank you)

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into account the padding in the `.col-2` declaration. When you have three columns adding up to a total of "100 % width" and then add padding, the result so to speak is "more than 100 % width", causing the overlapping behavior you observe.

One way around it is to declare the paddings in percent as well. If you don't like the resulting "elastic margins", you need to figure out a equation that works. Or check out [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or something similar (I mean you can either use it as is, or decipher their responsive solutions).

Comment: If you do not require absolute compatibility, you can also set [box-sizing: border-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) on the columns. This way, padding is subtracted from the `width` instead of added on top of it.

Comment: Here's a compatibility chart: [Can I Use CSS3 Box-sizing?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing).

Comment: I didn't made myself clear enough. Just edited the code and added a paragraph to the question. Do you see what I mean now? They respond to decreasing the size of the screen by decreazing sizes in all columns, but what I need is that the columns readjust positioning, becoming on top of each others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the css3 property box-sizing: border-box; This will wrap your padding into your div, so the width will be 50% only.
Please share your feedback if its helpful for your problem.

```
.col-2{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding:10px 20px 0px 20px;box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: its not working, you need to add the box-sizing: border-box; on .engage-row > div{},

Comment: I didn't made myself clear enough. Just edited the code and added a paragraph to the question. Do you see what I mean now? They respond to decreasing the size of the screen by decreazing sizes in all columns, but what I need is that the columns readjust positioning, becoming on top of each others.

Answer (score 0):

you mention 25% 50% 25% and a border of div so overlapped,
in this case use `box-sizing: border-box;`

```
.engage-row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.col-1 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
.col-2 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
}
.col-3 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
.footer-wfix {
  clear: both;
}

/* for illustrative purposes */

.engage-row {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.engage-row > div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;/*added one*/
}
```

Comment: I didn't made myself clear enough. Just edited the code and added a paragraph to the question. Do you see what I mean now? They respond to decreasing the size of the screen by decreazing sizes in all columns, but what I need is that the columns readjust positioning, becoming on top of each others.

Comment: okay,can you upload what you tried css in like a print screen

Comment: sure. This is what I had then: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwA1IuXMUSGIcjJ2TjdzX2pwTEE/view

later, I made the width of the column1 and column3 divs fixed, and the text in the middle div (column2) wraps until the div is around 300px wide, then it stacks. But the column3 stacks as soon as I decrease the size of the screen. What determines these stacking points? I would like the column3 div to stack also only when the column2 is 300px wide.
This is how it is now: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwA1IuXMUSGIU05KTDlWSF90OVU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This is what I needed (I couldn't be clear until I researched enough):
The left and right divs include images and I didn't want those to change size as I decrease the screen resolution. I wanted to input that adjustment in the middle div which contains only text and a subscription form.
The question/answer that drove me there:
[How to make element fill remaining width, when sibling has variable width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241186/how-to-make-element-fill-remaining-width-when-sibling-has-variable-width)

My testing fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/0gvxxpjj/

```
<!-- In html--->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
        <img src="">
    </div>
        <div class="col-3">
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <h3>Header</h3>
        <p>This is a paragraph that, along with the header, needs to wrap as the screen is resized</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- html ends here-->

/* CSS starts here */

.col-1 {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
.col-3 {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
}
.col-2{
    padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.row {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
.col-1, .col-3 {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.col-2 {
    border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

Hope it becomes useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to have the divs be in a 25% - 50% - 25% layout and after the browser shrinks beyond a certain size, they become 100% width and stack on top of each other.

This is done via media queries. What, essentially, happens is that you set some CSS rules inside a media query which adds to any previous CSS rules only when a certain condition has been met (in this case browser width). A rough example can be seen below.

These are the relevant parts:

This sets how the divs will look by default - full width.

```
.col-1,
.col-2,
.col-3 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This sets the widths of the divs to 25-50-25 once the browser width is larger than 768px.

```
@media all and (min-width:768px) {
  .col-1, .col-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-2 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

You can extend this example to the layout you desire.

```css
footer[role="contentinfo"] div {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.engage-row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.col-1,
.col-2,
.col-3 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.col-2 { 
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
}

.footer-wfix {
  clear: both;
}

/* for illustrative purposes */

.engage-row {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.engage-row > div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

@media all and (min-width:768px) {
  .col-1, .col-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-2 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer id="colophon" role="contentinfo">
<div class="footer-wrap">
  <div class="engage-row">
    <div class="col-1">
      Column 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      Column 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      Column 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-wfix">
      Footer Menu and Site-generator
  </div>
</div>
</footer><!-- #colophon -->
```

Comment: Glad that you bring that resume of how media queries work. I was just reading about it and will play with it a bit, test a few conditions to see which behavior looks best in different screen sizes.

I opted for a fixed width on col-1 and col-3, so the adjustments are made firstly at the level of the width and text contained in col-2. I'll spare the image resolutions and some processing, I guess, while using the stacking through media queries for adjustments in critical break points. First time doing this.